# $.expr error in jquery migration from v1.4.1 to v1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

I am using this plugin

> http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

and jquery v 1.4.1 and I want to migration from jquery v1.4.1 to v1.9.1.

This code:

```
var rows = $("#tableComments").find("tr:visible:not(:regex(class,^th))");
```

work very well with jquery v1.4.4 but I get this error in jquery v1.9.1

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
```

this error happens in the first line of the plugin,

```
var matchParams = match[3].split(',')
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's causing the error with such little information. *However* you can avoid the need for the `:regex` selector at all by using `filter()`. Also, if you're going to upgrade jQuery you may as well go to the latest on the 1.x branch if you need to keep IE supprort. I'd suggest 1.12.4 in that case, or 3.3.1 if you don't need legacy IE support.

Comment: Works fine with v1.9.1: https://jsfiddle.net/tte0jcvr/  Must be a problem somewhere else in your code.  See if you can create a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue.